# What's with the "I'ma tell 'em" in Normani's "Motivation"?

Tags: song-lyrics, normani

In Normani's song "[Motivation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKXSh14svlQ&ab_channel=NormaniVEVO)" (video slightly NSFW), there's a stanza that goes like this:

> You got a bad one, baby, don't you?
> Got a bad one, baby, don't you
> And we both know there's no
> One better, boy, no one better, boy
> Too late, won't make it, I'ma tell 'em (yeah)
> Get you naked, but I won't tell 'em
> 'Cause you know that there's no
> One better, boy, no one better, boy

I'm a bit confused what's happening with the two lines "Too late, won't make it, I'ma tell 'em" and "Get you naked, but I won't tell 'em". What's she going to tell (and to who) in the in "I'ma tell 'em" line, and why does it suddenly switch around to "but I won't tell 'em" immediately afterwards? I'm a bit lost as to what's going in in these two lines.